# Error calling icon in Weather App using React Native and Open Weather API

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, openweathermap

I have a weather application that uses native react and Open Weather API. I have problem when calling icon from weatherConditions.js file. Undefined is not an object weatherConditions[weather].icon

This is Home.js

```
import { API_KEY } from '../../utils/WeatherAPIKey';
import Weather from './../../components/Weather';

class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        temperature: 0,
        weatherCondition: null,
        error: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            this.fetchWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              error: 'Error Gettig Weather Condtions'
            });
          }
        );
    }

    fetchWeahter(lat, lon) {
        fetch(
          `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            // console.log(json);
            this.setState({
              temperature: json.main.temp,
              weatherCondition: json.weather[0].main,
              isLoading: false
            });
          });
      }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, weatherCondition, temperature } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    {isLoading ? (
                        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
                          <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Fetching The Weather</Text>
                        </View>
                      ) : (
                        <Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature} />
                      )}
            </View>
        );
    }
}


export default Home;
```

This is Weather.js

```
import ...
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { weatherConditions } from '../utils/WeatherConditions';

const Weather = ({ weather, temperature }) => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          size={72}
          name={weatherConditions[weather].icon}
          color={'#000'}
        />
        <Text style={styles.tempText}>{temperature}˚</Text>
      </View>
  );
};

Weather.propTypes = {
  temperature: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  weather: PropTypes.string
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})
```

And this is WeatherConditions.js

```
export const weatherConditions = {
    Rain: { icon: 'weather-rainy' },
    Clear: { icon: 'weather-sunny' },
    Thunderstorm: { icon: 'weather-lightning' },
    Clouds: { icon: 'weather-cloudy' },
    Snow: { icon: 'weather-snowy' },
    Drizzle: { icon: 'weather-hail' },
    Haze: { icon: 'weather-hail' },
    Mist: { icon: 'weather-fog' }
  };
```

Error screen when calling `{weatherConditions [weather] .icon}` in Weather.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to write
`if (weatherCondition !== undefined) {
  <Weather weather={weatherCondition} temperature={temperature} />
}`